# MySQL "field list es desconocida" FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, mariadb, insert

tengo un problema al insertar nuevos datos a una tabla que maneja un FOREIGN con binary.

Estas son las dos tablas:

Tabla 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_users` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type_document` enum('cc','ti') NOT NULL,
  `document` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('user','admin') NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
)
```

Tabla 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_operations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `value_net` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `value_total` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `method_pay` enum('transfer','cash') NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `dp_users` (`id`)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO `dp_operations` (`id_user`, `value_net`, `value_total`, `method_pay`) VALUES (0xb5e8e122-8c7c-11, '1000', '1000', 'transfer');
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
#1054 - La columna '8c7c' en field list es desconocida
```

Estoy usando XAMPP y MariaDB ¿Como puedo reescribir el código para solucionarlo?

Intente poner el FOREIGN como varchar y no resulto.

Comment: Si la columna es de tipo varchar el valor a insertar debe ir entre comillas `'0xb5e8e122-8c7c-11'`

Comment: A la segunda tabla le cambio el varchar por binary para coincidir el tipo de a llave primaria de la tabla dos. Y aun asi me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Entonces quita el `0x` del inicio y coloca el resto entre comillas  `'b5e8e122-8c7c-11'`

Answer (score 0):

En este sitio hay una pregunta con la misma interrogante y se le da respuesta. Es inserción en MySQL pero igual te debe servir puesto que es padre de MariaDB. Este es el link http://es.uwenku.com/question/p-kcbvvgty-bb.html. Espero que resuelva tu problema

Comment: Muchas gracias, logro resolver mi problema. Le di el HEX del id y le retire el `0x`. Pero ahora se me generó una pregunta, estoy usando un administrador de SQL **PhpMyAdmin**, y al revisar o editar un fila que cree, no me muestra ningún valor, pero aún así en la consulta me la muestra, ¿eso afecta en algo?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir con que no muestra ningún valor pero la consulta la muestra, si pudieras mostrar fotos te diría con más exactitud